# Reason why is better using Spring container or hashmap

Tags: java, spring, performance

I know maybe it doesnt have any sense, but I i'm implementing some methodology where you have a lot of objects inside a HashMap (Lets say 1000), all of them implements the same interface and all of them are singleton (all ready instantiated)
What is a better practice (we are talking about a lot of concurrency) using the hashmap or having all the objects inside the Spring container, and why is the bet option.
Thanks

Comment: Go ahead and write some code where you have one object depend on 5(call X) other objects and each such inner object depend upon 5 more(call Y) objects and then suddenly Y also depends on X.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i think you are doing an overkill if you want to use `Spring Container`, because it is a massive enterprise ready framework that was created to manage spring-based objects within your projects. Such objects could be *singletons* or not (*prototypes*). I'd rather skip it and i tell you why:

If you think that your data will not be thread-safe there is at least 3 options how you are able to resolve your issue:

1. Use concurrent collection from `JDK` (f.e. `ConcurrentHashMap`)
2. Implement your own thread-safe key->value collection
3. Think about synchronization at places where you use your `HashMap`.